# Is there any nth_value equivalent window function in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a window function , to get nth value from the partition/window
something like https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nth_value.html

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any inbuild function in spark for that. But you can get it by doing row_number() window function and then filtering it by 2, in where clause. Here you have to use sub query as in same query level you can't use window function value in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikhil Navin, nth_value function is available under org.apache.spark.sql.functions library from Spark 3.1.1 version.